# Can a payable function be internal?

Tags: solidity

I have the following setup of two internal and external functions. Is such a setup correct?

```
address public addr;

function addValue() external payable {
   _addValue(msg.value);
}

function _addValue(uint256 value) internal payable {
   addr.send(value);
}
```

Comment: answer updated.........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No internal and private function can't be declared as payable

you will get a compiler error

> TypeError: "internal" and "private" functions cannot be payable

The idea of having **payable modifier** is "to permission or prevent intentional and accidental value transfers" and using it twice first in external/public function and then again in internal function which is called by that function does not make sense :)

but you can use msg.value inside the internal function
so something like this

```
    function addValue() external payable {
       _addValue();
    }
    
    function _addValue() internal {
       payable(addr).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

Comment: So we can still transfer/call{value} even we don't have payable modifier on the internal function?

Comment: As long as the internal function is called inside a "public" or "external" function, you should be fine without the payable keyword on the internal function. Also make sure that the address receiving the funds is casted as "payable": `payable(_receiver).transfer(_amount)`